# Cannot publish my Android Unity app: APK in debug mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, app-store, apk

I'm trying to publish an app created with Unity 4 into the appstore, but it's still blocking me from uploading saying that my app is in debug mode.
I've checked the checkbox *development build* under Build Settings and I have signed it through the Publish Settings under the Player Settings.
Someone around the Internet says to change the System Variables for the JDK and I did it as well.

Comment: Please, read tag descriptions before using them.

Comment: Well, if the *development build* checkbox is checked, what do you expect?

Comment: Development build is for debugging, not for telling the build this is your final developed build.

Comment: On the beginning I've done without checking it but it didn't worked as well so I've tried checking it thinking was for the developed one!
At that time I didn't signed the apk so I'll try again when I'll be in the front of my pc.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox development build under Build Settings should **NOT** be checked when making a release build.